# add leading spaces so that character length of all cells in column equals max length

Tags: r

I would like to add leading spaces to `v2` so that all cells of `v2` have a character length of `maxchar`. I'm trying to combine different plots into one display, and this will help me with an alignment problem I'm having.

```
dat <- data.frame(v1=rep("item", 6),
                  v2=c(rep("10", 2),
                       rep("100", 2),
                       rep("1000", 2))
                  )
dat[2] <- as.character(dat[,2])
maxchar <- max(nchar(dat[,2]))
```

Comment: `dat$v2 <- stringr::str_pad(dat$v2, maxchar, "left")`

Comment: Solid, @NateDay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `format`

```
dat$v2 <- format(dat[,2], width = maxchar, justify = "right")
dat$v2
#[1] "  10" "  10" " 100" " 100" "1000" "1000"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paste(sapply(maxchar - nchar(dat$v2), function(n)
    paste(rep(" ", max(n,0)), collapse = "")), dat$v2, sep = "")
#[1] "  10" "  10" " 100" " 100" "1000" "1000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `stringi` package:

```
stringi::stri_pad_left(dat$v2, nchar(max(dat$v2)), pad = " ")
```

It will add spaces left according to the length of the max value.